# JS in PHP or transform PHP stuff into JS/jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, function

I generate some HTML input fields with returned data from my DB like this :

```
foreach ($result_single as $row2)
{ 

    if($row2->type == 'text') {
    echo "<li id='item-".$row2->rank."' class='list_item'>";
    echo "<textarea rows='2' id='".$row2->single_id."' cols='90' name='field[]' data-kind='text' >".$row2->content."</textarea>";
    echo "</li>";
    echo '<br />';
    }

    if($row2->type == 'title') {
    echo "<li id='item-".$row2->rank."' class='list_item'>";
    echo "<input type='text' id='".$row2->single_id."' name='field[]' value='".$row2->content."' data-kind='title' />";
    echo "</li>";
    echo '<br />'; 
    }
```

This will give me something like :

```
<li id="item-0" class="list_item"><input type="text" id="429" name="field[]" value="Title 1" data-kind="title"></li>    

<li id="item-1" class="list_item"><input type="text" id="430" name="field[]" value="Title 2" data-kind="title"></li>
```

Now I need to use JS functions into my PHP stuff (for example, I need JS function to populate the 'id' with something)

I know that I can't use JS in PHP because it's client side and so on but how can I translate my PHP stuff into JS? I mean to make the loop in JS then retrieve datas from the DB and usem y JS functions in?

Here's the JS function that I need to use into my PHP stuff :

```
function getLastField2(){
    var fields = jQuery(".list_item"), fieldName;

    if( !fields.length){
     return 0;   
    }
   fieldName = fields.last().prop("id");
    return parseInt(fieldName.match(numre)[1], 10) + 1;
}
```

Comment: Cannot tell what you are asking for. Your js function already retrieves the id of last `.list_item`

Comment: Actually, I need for example to call a js Function to delete an input field dynamically so in the input field I must call the 'delete_field' js function

Answer (score 0):

PHP - Us it to protect yourself, your database, your data integity, you assets.
Javascript - Use it to make the users esxperience more pleasant

For a metaphor - PHP is the oil, brakes on the rollercoster; Javascript is the art on the car

Please do not equate Javascript and PHP as doing the same function

Comment: Yes, but actually I need to use some JS stuff in PHP because the user can move fields and reorder them, he can also delete the fields and I need JS to do this dynamically so that's why I need to use JS in PHP I can't do something else :/

Thanks for your answer btw